# Duplicate keys in powershell

Tags: powershell

I trying to create a map in PowerShell with duplicate keys and unique values.

I know hashmap will not work, is there any other way to create a map for this duplicate keys.

```
$hashTables = @{}
$hashTables["$Identity_id"] = "$access"
```

Here, variable `$Identity_id` will have duplicates.

Comment: The whole point of a hashtable is that there can't be duplicate keys so you might need to rephrase your question. It seems what you want is to store duplicate values

Comment: I've done it for this post, but please [format your posts properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to provide a clearer example of what you mean by "duplicate key" and "unique values", but here's a way to do *something* that sounds like what you're asking...

Instead of trying to store duplicate keys in the hashtable (which you can't do anyway), store the *values* for each key as a collection and add the duplicates into the collection - e.g.

```
$data = @(
    [pscustomobject] @{ "Name" = "Eric"; "Address" = "1 The Street" },
    [pscustomobject] @{ "Name" = "Bob";  "Address" = "10 The Road" },
    [pscustomobject] @{ "Name" = "Eric"; "Address" = "29 Acacia Avenue" }
)

$map = @{};
$data | foreach-object {
    if( -not $map.Contains($_.Name) )
    {
        $map.Add($_.Name, [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new())
    }
    $map[$_.Name].Add($_.Address)
}

$map
# Name                           Value
# ----                           -----
# Bob                            {10 The Road}
# Eric                           {1 The Street, 29 Acacia Avenue}
```

This is basically a one-to-many mapping - each "value" is an ArrayList that contains all of the entries that have a "duplicate" key...